# Monitor status of an svnsync command?

Tags: monitoring, svn, svnserve

I have a svnsync command running and it is displaying output like:

```
...
Committed revision 39.
Copied properties for revision 39.
Committed revision 40.
Copied properties for revision 40.
Committed revision 41.
...
```

But how do I see that these revisions have been 'checked in' / synced properly right now (when I'm running the sync).

I tried:
    svnlook info /var/svn/repos

But that just shows something like:

```
2009-07-21 11:48:59 +0000 (Tue, 21 Jul 2009)
0
```

and then it jumped to:

```
2011-01-19 11:23:43 +0000 (Wed, 19 Jan 2011)
0
```

(and then back to 2009).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
nohup svnsync synchronize svn://www.example.com/repos &
[1] 23928
nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
```

and then

```
tail -f nohup.out
```